# The oozie job does not run with the message [AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM]

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I ran a shell job among the oozie examples.
However, YARN application is not executed.

Detail information YARN UI & LOG:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N8LBXZGttY3rhRTwv8cUEfK3WkWtvWJ-YV1q_fh_kks/edit

- YARN application status is

```
Application Priority:   0 (Higher Integer value indicates higher priority)
YarnApplicationState:   ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.
Queue:  default
FinalStatus Reported by AM: Application has not completed yet.
Finished:   N/A
Elapsed:    20mins, 30sec
Tracking URL:   ApplicationMaster
Log Aggregation Status: DISABLED
Application Timeout (Remaining Time):   Unlimited
Diagnostics:    AM container is launched, waiting for AM container to Register with RM
```

- Application Attempt status is

```
Application Attempt State:  FAILED
Elapsed:    13mins, 19sec
AM Container:   container_1607273090037_0001_02_000001
Node:   N/A
Tracking URL:   History
Diagnostics Info:   ApplicationMaster for attempt appattempt_1607273090037_0001_000002 timed out

    Node Local Request                   Rack Local     Request Off     Switch Request
Num Node Local Containers (satisfied by)    0       
Num Rack Local Containers (satisfied by)    0               0   
Num Off Switch Containers (satisfied by)    0               0                 1
```

- nodemanager log

```
2020-12-07 01:45:16,237 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.scheduler.ContainerScheduler: Starting container [container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001]
2020-12-07 01:45:16,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.container.ContainerImpl: Container container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001 transitioned from SCHEDULED to RUNNING
2020-12-07 01:45:16,267 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Starting resource-monitoring for container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001
2020-12-07 01:45:16,272 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor: launchContainer: [bash, /tmp/hadoop-oozie/nm-local-dir/usercache/oozie/appcache/application_1607273090037_0001/container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001/default_container_executor.sh]
2020-12-07 01:45:17,301 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001's ip = 127.0.0.1, and hostname = localhost.localdomain
2020-12-07 01:45:17,345 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.monitor.ContainersMonitorImpl: Skipping monitoring container container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001 since CPU usage is not yet available.
2020-12-07 01:45:48,274 INFO logs: Aliases are enabled
2020-12-07 01:54:50,242 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.localizer.ResourceLocalizationService: Cache Size Before Clean: 496756, Total Deleted: 0, Public Deleted: 0, Private Deleted: 0
2020-12-07 01:58:10,071 INFO SecurityLogger.org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server: Auth successful for appattempt_1607273090037_0001_000001 (auth:SIMPLE)
2020-12-07 01:58:10,078 INFO org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.ContainerManagerImpl: Stopping container with container Id: container_1607273090037_0001_01_000001
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: In the yarn UI, what resources does it say are available? How large of mapreduce job containers get created?

Comment: ●Cluster metric::Cluster Total Resource : 8192memory/8vcore  
●Cluster metric::Used Resource : 1024memory/1vcore
●Active Nodes : 1 (healthy)
●Queue(default)::Max Application Master Resource : 3072memory/1vcore
●Queue(default)::Used Application Master Resource : 1024memory/1vcore
          
Thankyou so mush.

Comment: And in the application history tab, are you able to find logs for the mapreduce tasks of that job?

Comment: please...help me. It is an emergency now....

Comment: Here Detail log : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N8LBXZGttY3rhRTwv8cUEfK3WkWtvWJ-YV1q_fh_kks/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: @OneCricketeer Please help me!!! begging you

Comment: Sorry, I can't see anything useful in that link

Comment: It is very important to me. Is there no way?

Comment: I see several log lines that say the app was submitted, allocated, ran, then succeeded. I don't see errors

Comment: I don't think resource problem...Are you agree?

Comment: Hard to say. I don't know what your job does; but the logs don't seem to say so. If anything, I'd say it's a configuration issue based on the `ApplicationMaster for attempt... timed out`, which I think would be configured in the yarn-site.xml of Oozie...

Comment: Thank you for your service. I'll try to solve it somehow...